# How am I meant to render different buttons based on a record in database when having a separated front & back end

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a separated front and back end. The front-end is JavaScript with Vue.js and the back-end is PHP with Laravel. The authentication is token based.

I have created a functionality which allows a user to wishlist sights and in order to wishlist a sight, the user has to click a button. When the user wishlists a sight, a record is inserted into the database and I can determine if a user has wishlisted a place based on it. Now I am trying to change which button is rendered when the component is loaded based on the record inside the database.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click='addTo("wishlistedPlaces")'>Remove from wishlist</button>
        <button @click='addTo("wishlistedPlaces")'>Add to wishlist</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            placeId: this.$route.params.placeid,
            sight: null
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/getSight/' + this.placeId)
        .then(response => {
            this.sight = response.data.result.result;
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
</script>
```

The GET request on mounted executes this PHP function which just returns the sight information:

```
public function getSight(Request $request, $placeId) {
    $get = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" . $placeId . "&key=");
    $result = json_decode($get);

    return response()->json([
        'result' => $result
    ], 201);
}
```

And this code, not yet implemented anywhere returns true or false based on whether the user has wishlisted a certain place or not:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
$checkIfWishlisted = $user->wishlistedPlaces->contains(function ($place) use ($placeId) {
    return $place->place_id == $placeId;
});
```

So my question is where exactly in the back-end should I check if the user has wishlisted a place so I could send the boolean response to the front-end and then how should I use that boolean in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am trying to change which button is rendered when the component
>   is loaded based on the record inside the database.

One way would to create another data property to hold information about if the user has it on whishlist or not

```
data() {
  return {
    onWishlist: false
  }
}
```

Under mounted make another axios call.

```
mounted() {
  axios.get('/checkWishlist/' + this.placeId)
    .then(response => {
      this.onWishlist= response.data;
     })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
```

In the template make a v-if statement on the buttons

```
<button v-if="onWishlist" @click='addTo("wishlistedPlaces")'>Remove from wishlist</button>
<button v-if="!onWishlist" @click='addTo("wishlistedPlaces")'>Add to wishlist</button>
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/EzEBWo